# How to stop git-daemon on debian

Tags: linux, debian, service, git

I'm running debian lenny server, and I've installed git on it. Now there is a git-daemon process (and appropriate opened port), but there is no /etc/init.d/git script that I could stop. I know there is /etc/sv/git-daemon/run but that doesn't help me stopping it either.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`git-daemon` under Debian is managed by [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/).

```
sv stop git-daemon
```

should do it.

Comment: Thanks, tried to find this, but I couldn't get good answer.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I recall the git-daemon-run package should provide the /etc/init.d/git-daemon

Comment: nope, found that on google, but doesn' work

Comment: If you want to remove the package as well use `dpkg -r git-daemon-run`. Will also have the side-effect of stopping the service.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the README.Debian you can make a symlink :

> See the sv(8) program on how to manage the service, or, alternatively,
>   create a symbolic link /etc/init.d/git-daemon pointing to /usr/bin/sv to
>   have an LSB compatible interface to control it:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/sv /etc/init.d/git-daemon
/etc/init.d/git-daemon status
```

Answer (score 0):

In Debian 11, you can stop it from coming up during bootup by editing the `/etc/default/git-daemon` and changing the `GIT_DAEMON_ENABLE` to `”false”`.